# Finding the analytical solution to this second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to find the solution to;

$$y''= \frac 2xy' - \frac {2}{x^2}y - \frac 1{x^2},\ y(1)=0,\ y'(1)=1 $$

By observing that the first two terms on the RHS exactly for the derivative of some function;

Im aware that the derivative of the coefficient of $y'$ term is $2ln(x)$ and then the derivative of the coefficient of $y$ is the derivative of $\frac 2x$.

Could somebody please offer me some direction?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).. You should find that $$\frac{2}{x}y' - \frac{2}{x^{2}}y = 2 \bigg(\frac{1}{x}y \bigg)'$$

Also, the _derivative_ of the coefficient of $y' \ne 2\ln(x)$.. Thats the _integral_ of $\frac{2}{x}$

Comment: Sorry about that was my mistake :S wasn't thinking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$
\frac{2}{x}y' - \frac{2}{x^2}y -\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{2}{x} y + \frac{1}{x} \right ).
$$

Comment: I had this then somehow doubted myself, now I can equate this RHS to the second derivative and solve by integrating? Well ill try this anyway thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yes, integrating both sides yields a first order ODE with a constant.  After this step it should be relatively easy to solve.